# Getting Hudson to connect to a sasl svnserve install

Tags: svn, hudson, sasl

We are unable to get hudson to connect to our SVN server. We are using SASL and we can connect just fine with tortoisesvn and the standard cli client. However when we try to use hudson we get this error:

```
Passing user name someuser1 and password you entered
Failed to authenticate: svn: Authorization failed
FAILED: svn: Authorization failed
```

StackTrace:

```
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNAuthenticationException: svn: Authorization failed
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:62)

    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:51)

    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.sasl.SVNSaslAuthenticator.authenticate(SVNSaslAuthenticator.java:138)

    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNConnection.authenticate(SVNConnection.java:173)

    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNRepositoryImpl.authenticate(SVNRepositoryImpl.java:1260)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNRepositoryImpl.openConnection(SVNRepositoryImpl.java:1238)

    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNRepositoryImpl.testConnection(SVNRepositoryImpl.java:95)

    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$DescriptorImpl.postCredential(SubversionSCM.java:1743)

    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$DescriptorImpl.doPostCredential(SubversionSCM.java:1700)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:259)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:126)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:65)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:79)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:30)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:534)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$7.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:219)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:30)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:534)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:450)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:132)

    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:45)

    at winstone.ServletConfiguration.execute(ServletConfiguration.java:249)

    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.forward(RequestDispatcher.java:335)

    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:378)

    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:94)

    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:86)

    at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:195)

    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:368)

    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:47)

    at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:195)

    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:368)

    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)

    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)

    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:164)

    at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:195)

    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:368)

    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.forward(RequestDispatcher.java:333)

    at winstone.RequestHandlerThread.processRequest(RequestHandlerThread.java:244)

    at winstone.RequestHandlerThread.run(RequestHandlerThread.java:150)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**FYI**: The username and password are correct!

Comment: I guess you used the same username with Hudson, than the one you used with tortoise. (SVN User name and Windows account, should be both the same for Hudson and your test) Frequent problem is running Hudson under the local_system account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hudson uses java's SVNKit to connect; It seems to have a long history of not working well with SASL.... might I suggest ssh+svn ?  Either way you now at least have a hint.